# Conditionally repeating headers

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have data that requires the header to repeat if there is data in the lower cell. Here is an example.

```
Parking light

1157A

Front turn signa

l1157A 

11157

Rear turn signal 

7440

Tail light 

168

7443
```

I need to make it look like this:

```
Parking light

1157A

Front turn signal

1157A

Front turn signal

1157

Rear turn signal

7440

Tail light

168

Tail light

7443
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a data cell starts with a number and an header cell does not, this should do the trick. It loops from the active cell downwards until it finds written cells.

```
Sub repeatHeadings()

    Dim header As String

    While ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 <> ""

        If IsNumeric(Left(ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1, 1)) Then
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = header
        Else
            header = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1
        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select

    Wend

End Sub
```